# How to enter a fraction in formula editor of Word?

Tags: macos, worksheet-function, microsoft-word-2011

How can I enter the following fraction in Word for Mac (with the keyboard, clicking twice every time I need it is obviously not a solution)?

[image]

Comment: In Word 2010 for PC, while in equation mode you just type `1/2` and it converts it to that fraction automatically. not sure if it's the same

Comment: At least in Word 2007, when the equation editor is active, you can press Alt+J (to switch to the Design tab), F (to open the Fraction dropdown) and Enter (to select the first option, stacked fraction).

Comment: @jay: I can't believe I didn't try that. Works for `(x+y+z)/(a+b+c)` too! If you post it as an answer I'll gladly accept

Comment: sweet! glad they kept the shortcuts, makes it easier for users to transition between platforms. also see the given link for more!

Comment: Somehow offtopic, but somehow related though. [Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Math-AutoCorrect-symbols-b8b463d9-f47d-45c4-a00f-9245c2b38843?CorrelationId=988872c4-00ba-4aeb-805b-33ce44eba357&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA010064598)'s a list of commands you can use to stop switching between keyboard and mouse. Might be useful for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Word 2010 for PC while in an equation you can just type `1/2` and it should convert it to a fraction. Other notable shortcuts include `x^n` for x<sup>n</sup> and `x_n` for x<sub>n</sub>.

Here's a more [elaborate list](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=474856) of such shortcuts.

[image: 1/2 in linear form]
*turns into*
[image: automatically turns into a fraction]

This should be the same for World for Mac 2011!